# Python looping and Pandas rank/index quirk

Tags: python, loops, sorting, pandas, indexing

This question pertains to one posted here:
[Sort dataframe rows independently by values in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411724/sort-dataframe-rows-independently-by-values-in-another-dataframe)

In the linked question, I utilize a Pandas Dataframe to sort each row independently using values in another Pandas Dataframe. The function presented there works perfectly every single time it is directly called. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

##Generate example dataset
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
d3 = {}
d4 = {}
## generate data:
np.random.seed(5)
for col in list("ABCDEF"):
    d1[col] = np.random.randn(12)
    d2[col+'2'] = np.random.random_integers(0,100, 12)
    d3[col+'3'] = np.random.random_integers(0,100, 12)
    d4[col+'4'] = np.random.random_integers(0,100, 12)

t_index = pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-31', periods = 12, freq = "M")
#place data into dataframes   
dat1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, index = t_index)
dat2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, index = t_index)
dat3 = pd.DataFrame(d3, index = t_index)
dat4 = pd.DataFrame(d4, index = t_index)

## Functions 
def sortByAnthr(X,Y,Xindex, Reverse=False):
    #order the subset of X.index by Y
    ordrX = [x for (x,y) in sorted(zip(Xindex,Y), key=lambda pair: pair[1],reverse=Reverse)]
    return(ordrX)

def OrderRow(row,df):
    ordrd_row = df.ix[row.dropna().name,row.dropna().values].tolist()
    return(ordrd_row)

def r_selectr(dat2,dat1, n, Reverse=False):
    ordr_cols = dat1.apply(lambda x: sortByAnthr(x,dat2.loc[x.name,:],x.index,Reverse),axis=1).iloc[:,-n:]
    ordr_cols.columns = list(range(0,n)) #assign interpretable column names

    ordr_r = ordr_cols.apply(lambda x: OrderRow(x,dat1),axis=1)
    return([ordr_cols, ordr_r])

## Call functions    
ordr_cols2,ordr_r = r_selectr(dat2,dat1,5)

##print output:
print("Ordering set:\n",dat2.iloc[-2:,:])
print("Original set:\n", dat1.iloc[-2:,:])
print("Column ordr:\n",ordr_cols2.iloc[-2:,:])
```

As can be checked, the columns of dat1 are correctly ordered according to the values in dat2.

**However**, when called from a loop over dataframes, it does not rank/index correctly and produces completely dubious results. Although I am not quite able to recreate the problem using the reduced version presented here, the idea should be the same.

```
## Loop test:
out_dict = {}
data_dicts = {'dat2':dat2, 'dat3': dat3, 'dat4':dat4}

for i in range(3):
    #this outer for loop supplies different parameter values to a wrapper
    #function that calls r_selectr.
    for key in data_dicts.keys():
        ordr_cols,_ = r_selectr(data_dicts[key], dat1,5)
        out_list.append(ordr_cols)

        #do stuff here
#print output:
print("Ordering set:\n",dat3.iloc[-2:,:])
print("Column ordr:\n",ordr_cols2.iloc[-2:,:])
```

In my code (almost completely analogous to the example given here), the ordr_cols are no longer ordered correctly for any of the sorting data frames.

I currently solve the issue by separating the ordering and indexing operations with r_selectr into two separate functions. That, for some reason, resolves the issue though I have no idea why.

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the input. The code actually contains a few lines to generate the random dataset that's being used herein. Through my use of stackoverflow, that has seemed to be standard practice. I edited the above to include print statements to print the output dataframes.